# How can I establish a wireless link between my PC and TenTec 506 / chipKIT UNO32 using USB port?

Tags: hf, diy, transceiver, computer-control

I have a TenTec 506 HF transceiver that uses a Digilent chipKIT UNO32 microcontroller. My PC running Teraterm (serial connection) or the MPIDE monitor is connected to the microcontroller's mini B USB port to read frequency, RIT, voltage, etc. I would like to replace the USB cable (USB A to USB mini B) that runs between the TenTec's controller and my PC with inexpensive USB wireless devices or Bluetooth.
Can anyone suggest devices that will allow me do this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really sounds like it is more work than it is worth. I am starting to get the idea that a Bluetooth shield or Wifi shield might be the avenue to pursue if I don't run into input or output issues with the microcontroller and transceiver.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific model recommendations, but I once saw that there existed simple dongles which convert between Bluetooth serial and RS-232 serial. If you connected such a device to the microcontroller, then after you pair your PC with the dongle you will have a standard serial device on the PC you can point your control programs at.

However, to do this you would have to modify the Uno32 board by cutting the traces between the microcontroller and the USB interface chip (nets `U1RX/SDI1/RF2` and `U1TX/SDO1/RF3` in [this schematic](http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/CHIPKIT-UNO32/ChipKIT%20Uno32_bysa_c_sch.pdf), if it matches the model you have) and wiring in a serial connector, and probably including a RS232-to-3.3V-logic level converter. (Or maybe there are 3.3V-logic Bluetooth serial modules suitable for direct wiring in, which would save some parts.)

I expect that a wireless connection which substituted the USB cable rather than bypassing USB would be more expensive and/or require more specialized driver software, though.

Again, I haven't actually done much research on this — this is just an idea off the top of my head that should be feasible.